# check unzip each archive to separate subdir as default

Tags: kubuntu, zip

I am using kUbuntu v20.4 and want to set

Unpack separate subdir checked by default

Motivation:

It often happens that I unzip a zip in my Downloads folder and then I have a bunch of files unzipped in that beside many other downloaded files.

I want the default position to be that this zip will be unziped in a *new* folder or each archive is unzipped into a separate folder.

If I check it manually it’s ok for me, but if I forget then it’s a mess of files around and difficult to repair. So to have it by default or that the GUI can remember the last config (much better in my opinion) it would be very helpful.

How is the default option configured?

Answer (score 4):

`unzip` has a `-d {dir2unxip}`

There is no automatic way to do this through a setting. You will have to supply a directory using the `-d` option. The command will ask to overwrite if the dir exists and if you did not force it.

The best you can do is to create an alias for `zip` that changes it to `zip -d` so you are told to supply a directory. But that would mean you HAVE to supply the zip file itself as the next argument and need to remeber to use this new function.

```
alias myunzip="zip -d"
```

You would type ...

```
 myunzip 2 zipfile.zip
```

and the contents get created in subdirectory `2`

Answer (score 4):

### Automatic system assuming using defaults to unzip into subdirectories

You can make an automatic system assuming that you unzip using defaults, simply `unzip filename.zip` using the following shellscript and put it in path before the `unzip`, for example as `/usr/local/bin/unzip`.

You should also run `source ~/.bashrc` in order to make the current bash (terminal window) aware of the local unzip script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" != "" ]
then
 newdir=${1%.zip}
 if test -s "$1" && [ "$newdir" != "$1" ]
 then
  if ! test -d "$newdir" 
  then
   echo "creating $newdir and cd-ing to it and unzipping in it"
   mkdir "$newdir"
   curdir="$(pwd)"
   cd "$newdir"
   /usr/bin/unzip "../$1"
   cd "$curdir"
  else
   echo "Cannot create new directory '$newdir'.
If you want to create a directory with that name and extract to it,
remove the current directory with that name, but check first
what it contains (maybe valuable data) !!!"
   exit 1
  fi
 else
  echo "Not a zipfile: '$1'"
  exit 1
 fi
else
 echo "Usage: ${0##*/} <zipfile>"
 exit 1
fi
```

This assumes that you are happy with subdirectories with the name of the zipfile (minus `.zip`).

**Try the shellscript method in a test directory before doing it where you have real data**, so that you see that it is doing what you want it to do.